# Duplicate a variable in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, clone

I'm trying to swap two variables in ActionScript.

I tried using:

```
a = 42
b = 50

tempvar = a
a = b
b = tempvar
```

to switch, but this doesn't work because the variables still reference the original value, so if I set b = a, and then change a, b changes as well.

in ruby, you have clone(), but I don't know a similar method for AS3.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works fine. Surely you have not shown all your code?

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
public class SwapTest extends Sprite
{
    public function SwapTest()
    {
        var a:int=42;
        var b:int=50;
        var temp:int=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
        trace("a="+a);
        trace("b="+b);
    }
}
```

Traces

```
a=50
b=42
```

No clone required. Even the following untyped code, that more closely follows your example gives the same output:

```
        var a=42;
        var b=50;
        var temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
        trace("a="+a);
        trace("b="+b);
```

How are you declaring a,b and tempVar? Is this timeline code?

Comment: The reason this works is because you're using primitive types like int.  Primitive types copy on assignment, while object types like Arrays use references.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tempvar:uint = new uint(a);
a = new uint(b);
b = tempvar;
```